# AssertionError: Element odoo has extra content: record, line 4

Tags: odoo-11, odoo-view

I'm trying to add multi field to timesheet module to work as a tasks manage app i did inheritance to account.analytic.line the problem is in the view i got that error "AssertionError: Element odoo has extra content: record, line 4"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<odoo>
  <record id="todo_timesheet_line_tree" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="hr_timesheet.hr_timesheet_line_tree"/>
    <field name="model">account.analytic.line</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml"/>
    <field name="task_id" position="after">
      <field name="priority"/>
    </field>
    <field name="company_id" groups="base.group_multi_company" position="before">
      <field name="gov_department"/>
      <field name="priority"/>
      <field name="date_deadline"/>
    </field>
  </record>
</odoo>


from odoo import models, fields, api

class TodoTask(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'account.analytic.line'
    startdate=fields.Date('start Date', required=True, index=True, default=fields.Date.context_today)
    date_deadline=fields.Date('Deadline', required=True, index=True, default=fields.Date.context_today)
    priority = fields.Selection(selection=[('1', 'فوري'), ('2','هام جدا' ),('3','اقل اهمية')])
    is_done = fields.Boolean ('Done?')

    gov_department = fields.Many2one('govauthority','الجهة الحكومية')






class govauthority(models.Model):
    govname = fields.Char('GOV_Department', size=25, required=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is in this line

```
<field name="arch" type="xml" />
```

You closed the tag while you really should not. Within this tag the actual XML body should be.

```
<record id="todo_timesheet_line_tree" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="hr_timesheet.hr_timesheet_line_tree" />
    <field name="model">account.analytic.line</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <field name="task_id" position="after">
            <field name="priority" />
        </field>
        <field name="company_id" groups="base.group_multi_company" position="before">
            <field name="gov_department" />
            <field name="priority" />
            <field name="date_deadline" />
        </field>
    </field>
</record>
```

Comment: Thank you so much brother! I really appreciate